# Overwolf Minecraft forge error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc, mods, minecraft-mods

I have an app called overwolf and curseforge, when i open forge and select a modpack, i click the orange play button and it says this "Launching Game" and then nothing happens

Comment: this breaks the guidelines for minecraft mods.

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of overwolf crash Minecraft, Update it to fix this.
Source: Minecraft discord voulenteer support team